# Not able to configure mongodb in laravel framework

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, composer-php

I am not able to integrate mongoDB is laravel project. Installation of 'jenssegers/mongodb' Package in the project fails. Following are the error prints.

Output of command `composer require jenssegers/mongodb`

```
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install jenssegers/mongodb v3.6.3
    - Conclusion: don't install jenssegers/mongodb v3.6.2
    - Conclusion: don't install jenssegers/mongodb v3.6.1
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v7.5.1
    - Installation request for jenssegers/mongodb ^3.6 -> satisfiable by jenssegers/mongodb[v3.6.0, v3.6.1, v3.6.2, v3.6.3].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.5.1
    - jenssegers/mongodb v3.6.0 requires illuminate/events ^5.8|^6.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/events[5.8.x-dev, 6.x-dev, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.1.0, v6.10.0, v6.11.0, v6.12.0, v6.13.0, v6.13.1, v6.14.0, v6.15.0, v6.15.1, v6.16.0, v6.17.0, v6.17.1, v6.18.0, v6.18.1, v6.18.2, v6.18.3, v6.18.4, v6.18.5, v6.2.0, v6.3.0, v6.4.1, v6.5.0, v6.5.1, v6.5.2, v6.6.0, v6.6.1, v6.6.2, v6.7.0, v6.8.0].
    - don't install illuminate/events 5.8.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.5.1
    - don't install illuminate/events 6.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.5.1
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.5.1
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.11|don't install laravel/framework v7.5.1
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.12|don't install laravel/framework v7.5.1
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.14|don't install laravel/framework v7.5.1
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.15|don't install laravel/framework v7.5.1
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.17|don't install laravel/framework v7.5.1
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.18|don't install laravel/framework v7.5.1
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.19|don't install laravel/framework v7.5.1
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.2|don't install laravel/framework v7.5.1
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.20|don't install laravel/framework v7.5.1
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.22|don't install laravel/framework v7.5.1
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.24|don't install laravel/framework v7.5.1
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.27|don't install laravel/framework v7.5.1
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.28|don't install laravel/framework v7.5.1
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.29|don't install laravel/framework v7.5.1
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.3|don't install laravel/framework v7.5.1
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.30|don't install laravel/framework v7.5.1
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.31|don't install laravel/framework v7.5.1
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.32|don't install laravel/framework v7.5.1
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.33|don't install laravel/framework v7.5.1
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.34|don't install laravel/framework v7.5.1
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.35|don't install laravel/framework v7.5.1
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.36|don't install laravel/framework v7.5.1
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.4|don't install laravel/framework v7.5.1
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.8|don't install laravel/framework v7.5.1
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.9|don't install laravel/framework v7.5.1
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.5.1
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.0.1|don't install laravel/framework v7.5.1
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.0.2|don't install laravel/framework v7.5.1
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.0.3|don't install laravel/framework v7.5.1
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.0.4|don't install laravel/framework v7.5.1
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.1.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.5.1
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.2.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.5.1
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.3.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.5.1
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.4.1|don't install laravel/framework v7.5.1
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.5.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.5.1
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.5.1|don't install laravel/framework v7.5.1
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.5.2|don't install laravel/framework v7.5.1
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.6.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.5.1
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.6.1|don't install laravel/framework v7.5.1
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.6.2|don't install laravel/framework v7.5.1
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.7.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.5.1
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.8.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.5.1
    - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v7.5.1, required as ^7.0) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v7.5.1].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Laravel framewok verion - php artisan --version -> **Laravel Framework 7.5.1**

MongoDB version -> **4.0.5**

PHP version -> **7.4.3**

PHP driver for mongodb is installed. 
[image]

Answer (score 3):

**I had the same problem. After checking their Github issues, I got the below solution which worked for me.**

```
composer require jenssegers/mongodb:dev-develop
```

Answer (score 1):

Try - composer require jenssegers/mongodb dev-develop

As it might still be under development for laravel version 7

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem even after running `composer require jenssegers/mongodb:dev-develop`

doing this helped me:
`composer require jenssegers/mongodb:dev-develop --ignore-platform-reqs`

Answer (score 0):

Before package installation you need to install PHP driver for MongoDB. You can install it by `pecl` as follows:

```
sudo pecl install mongodb
```

For more detailed info you can see [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.pecl.php).

next you can run your mongodb by this command:

```
sudo service mongod start
```

For windows and mac, you can their own alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `jenssegers/mongodb` in it's current form only supports the illuminate-ecosystem (and therefore Laravel) up to version 6.

Therefore you'd have to downgrade laravel to the newest version in the 6-range.

7 is just available since 5 weeks, so it may take some time until other packages in the eco-system have updated version constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know the pros and cons of it, but this worked for me.

`composer require jenssegers/mongodb:*`